# Filtering pandas dataframe on 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below dataframe. How can I filter it to find only unique emails that are in both event years (e.g. 2022 and 2023)?

```
df_current = pd.DataFrame({'Email':['Bob_Jones@gmail.com', 'Mike_Smith@gmail.com', 'Mike_Smith@gmail.com', 'Bob_Jones@gmail.com'],
               'Tickets Sold':[1, 2, 1, 1], 'Year':['2022', '2023', '2023', '2023']})


df_desired = pd.DataFrame({'Email':['Bob_Jones@gmail.com', 'Bob_Jones@gmail.com'],
               'Tickets Sold':[1, 1], 'Year':['2022', '2023']})
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this out

```
duplicates = df_current.duplicated(subset=['Email'], keep=False)
df_desired = df_current[duplicates]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way you could use:

```py
import pandas as pd

result = df_current.loc[df_current.groupby('Email')['Year'].transform('nunique') >= 2, :]

print(result)
# Prints:
#                  Email  Tickets Sold  Year
# 0  Bob_Jones@gmail.com             1  2022
# 2  Bob_Jones@gmail.com             1  2023
```